# What does it mean when a session is highlighted in red in the PgAdmin dashboard?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I've noticed sessions being highlighted in red recently though this never occurred in the past which leads me to believe it is a new feature. It appears to only occur on hanging queries. I looked through the PgAdmin documentation as well as change logs for all recent updates but could not find an explanation. Here is an example of how it appears:

[image: PgAdmin session highlighted in red.]

Answer (score 10):

The session is running a query (state `active`), but is blocked and has to wait.

Often that blocking event is a database lock, but in your case it is `IO: DataFileRead`, which means it is waiting for an I/O request to complete.

If you see a lot of active sessions in that state, that is a clear indication that your I/O system is overloaded.

Comment: Does the documentation for this highlight feature exist anywhere?

Comment: I couldn't find it.

Comment: I have a similar situation, a PID appears in red and is active with the wait event = "Client: WalSenderWaitForWAL" it is a subscriber logical replication connection. Both the publisher and subscriber are development databases with no loads at all. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @HMarioD I'd say that everything is fine. pgAdmin just isn't hip to the fact that WAL senders are different from other backends.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thank you very much. I was concerned with that matter.

Answer (score 3):

The highlight means that the current query has been running for a long time. It could be blocked, but that is not always the case. If it is blocked, it should have more information in the "Blocking PIDs" column.
In Preferences -> Dashboards -> Display, you can set threshold times for Warning and Alert (= Red(?)).
More information is found [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/dashboards-pgadmin-4).